# WildFly Returns Forbidden Or Missing Template Error

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I have successfully deployed a WAR file using WildFly 10. However, when trying to access it from a browser using http://localhost:8080/AppName I receive a 403 error, Forbidden.

If I load the app as a JSP using http://localhost:8080/AppName/WebContent/index.jsp, the index.jsp is found, but an error occurs within the index.jsp when trying to reference includes, for example:

/pages/someinclude.jsp not found

The template someinclude.jsp does exist in the pages directory directly beneath index.jsp, so the web root reference /pages/someinclude.jsp is correct, provided that the web root is WebContent/.

I'm running WildFly as a standalone server, and there is no /WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml to modify the context-root. Can someone explain what's happening and how I might fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Without some more information there isn't any way to help you.  We have no idea how your application is structured, how it's packaged, and what the code is doing.  Can you create a very small, reproducible sample?

Comment: The app isn't mine. It would take too long to derive a minimal version. I wish there were some basic troubleshooting tactics to try in order to at least rule them out.